# How to make opacity animation when text replacement

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation, css-animations, setinterval

i have this code that replace index in array every 5s to display different text

```
    const [articles, setArticles] = useState(0)

    const [imageBanner, setImageBanner] = useState([
    {
        text: "blah blah"
    },
    {
        text: "blah blah"
    },
    {}
])

   setInterval(() => {
        if (articles < 3) {
            setArticles(articles => articles + 1)
        }
        console.log(articles)
    }, 5000);
```

and i would like to know how can i make opacity animation when text replacement

what i tried before

```
@keyframes example {
0% {
    opacity: 0;
}
3% {
    opacity: 0.2;
}
6% {
    opacity: 0.4;
}
8% {
    opacity: 0.6;
}
10% {
    opacity: 0.8;
}
50% {
    opacity: 1;
}
90% {
    opacity: 0.8;
}
93% {
    opacity: 0.6;
}
96% {
    opacity: 0.4;
}
98% {
    opacity: 0.2;
}
100% {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

}

But the timing of it is not good

Comment: What does the text replacement means? The  `setArticles()` function?

Comment: this code using React so i update the state every 5s

Comment: I just posted a question. Not sure if it solved your problem because I can't fully understand what you want to do.

Comment: i tired but not working, let me simplify my issue: i change the text to different text every 5s so when to text replace i want to change it with opacity

Comment: Could you share more about how the rest of your component regarding the articles state?

Comment: @DanCr, update the code. See if it works

Comment: Emil i Update my code.

Comment: James this not working fine yet

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a `setInterval`, use the timing of the animation to change the text of the element.

By using a `useRef` hook we can create a reference to our animation element. Then listen to [`animationiteration`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/animationiteration_event) event on that element. This event will trigger every time it starts again.

For this to work we'll need to modify the CSS animation and tell it either to go N times or `infinite` times.

When the event is called, use `setArticleIndex` to count to the next item (or to 0 whenever the end of the list is reached).

```js
const { useRef, useState, useEffect } = React;

const imageBanners = [
  { text: "Hello There" },
  { text: "General Kenobi" },
  { text: "You are a bold one" }
];

const Component = () => {
  const animationEl = useRef(null);
  const [articleIndex, setArticleIndex] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    animationEl.current.addEventListener('animationiteration', () => {
      setArticleIndex(currentIndex => {
        if (currentIndex + 1 < imageBanners.length) {
          return currentIndex + 1;
        } else {
          return 0;
        }
      });
    });
  }, []);
  
  return (
     <div className="fade-in-out" ref={animationEl}>
       {imageBanners[articleIndex].text}
     </div>
  );
};

const app = document.querySelector('#app');
ReactDOM.render(
  <Component />, 
  app
);
```

```css
@keyframes fade-in-out {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  5%,
  95% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.fade-in-out {
  animation: fade-in-out 5s both infinite;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: what about if i want to use this function inside useEffect already i used to call api ? i can't secces

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't understand. If there is more to your to your component to take into account, then you should add that to your original question. Please be as detailed as possible. However, does this solve your animation issue?

Answer (score 0):

This code should work by using `animation` and `animation-fill-mode`.

```css
@keyframes move {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  3% {
    opacity: 0.2;
  }
  6% {
    opacity: 0.4;
  }
  8% {
    opacity: 0.6;
  }
  10% {
    opacity: 0.8;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  90% {
    opacity: 0.8;
  }
  93% {
    opacity: 0.6;
  }
  96% {
    opacity: 0.4;
  }
  98% {
    opacity: 0.2;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

h1 {
  animation-name: move;
  animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
```

```html
<h1>Hello, World</h1>
```